# Matrix Solving Method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve my matrix method:
$$3y+4x=2xy$$ and
$$9y-2x=\frac{5xy}{2}$$

My solution 
Here:
$$3y+4x=2xy$$
Dividing both sides by $xy$
$$\frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{y}=2$$----(1)
Again,
$$9y-2x=\frac{5xy}{2}$$
$$18y-4x=5xy$$
Dividing both sides by $xy$
$$\frac{18}{x}-\frac{4}{y}=5$$-------(2).

My solution ends here, now, whats next?

Comment: What matrix ???

Answer (score 2):

Now if you add the two equations after dividing by $xy$ you get $$\frac 3x+\frac {18}x=7$$

Note that you should consider whether $x$ or $y$ could be zero before dividing by $xy$

Answer (score 0):

You rewrite

$$\frac3x+\frac4y=2,\\\frac{18}x-\frac4y=5,$$

with an obvious change of variable

$$3x'+4y'=2,\\18x'-4y'=5$$

and get a linear system which causes no difficulty.

This is only valid if $xy\ne0$. By inspection, $x=y=0$ is another solution (and there are no other).

Comment: but how do I solve this by matrix method.?